# Can't read or parse Plain String Response from CXF REST Web Service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

A REST Service is implemented correctly in SpringMVC, deployed, and returns the correct result string,

```
@RestController
public class RESTServiceController {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json") 
    @RequestMapping("/restUrl")
    public String getResult() {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("result", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

When testing this Web Service I get the correct output,

```
{"result":true}
```

The problem is the caller gets the Response object via CXF, but I don't know how to parse the Response. I don't need a custom object. All I need is the direct string, I just want to see my output string.

```
String restServiceURI = "http://www.asite.com/restUrl";
WebClient client = WebClient.create(restServiceURI,true);
Response resp = client.get();
//String entity = (String)resp.getEntity; <-- Also tried this to cast to a string
```

The issue is, the Response length is 0, Status is 302.
The `getEntity InputStream` brings back an `EmptyInputStream` based on what the debugger shows.

The Response object doesn't have any info that I can see in the debugger.

How do I just get my direct string back? Is there an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying mix both Spring Rest and CxF rest. Either use Spring Rest or CXF Rest.

If you want to use Spring Rest as shown below

```
@Service
public class RESTServiceController {

    @RequestMapping("/restUrl")
    public @ResponseBody MyClass getResult() {
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

or CXF as shown below.

```
@Service
public class RESTServiceController {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json") 
    public MyClass getResult() {
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

**Note:** You need not use json conversion explicitly, both Spring Rest and CXF has to feature to convert your object to json string.

However your issue doesn't stop here, I believe you've enabled spring-security, which is sending redirect(302) response, with login page.  You can verify response from server by enabling logging in client side.

```
        WebClient.getConfig(client).getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        WebClient.getConfig(client).getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```